# Meteor, autoform schema error after deployment

Tags: javascript, meteor, schema, meteor-autoform

My app uses autoform. I deployed it.
In local testing I do not have any problems

After deploying, I received an error message in the console:

```
"Error: AutoForm: form with id "newTerritoryForm" needs either "schema" or "collection" attribute"
```

I define schema in common.js:

```js
Schemas={};

Schemas.newTerritories= new SimpleSchema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        label: 'Nome'
    },
    number:{
        type: Number,
        label: 'Numero'
    }
});
```

And my client side is:

```js
Template.territories.helpers({
    Schemas: function(){
        return Schemas;
    },
...
});
```

And my html is:

```html
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
{{#autoForm schema=Schemas.newTerritories id="newTerritoryForm" class="ui form fluid" type="method" meteormethod="newTerritory"}}
...
{{/autoForm}}
</div>
```

I repeat, if on the local machine it works, but after deploying it, it does not work.

Why?

Comment: Do you have `Schemas={};` at the top of more than one js file? Meteor loads each js file separately in dev mode, but bundles them all together into one file when you deploy. You may have just been lucky up until now that this file was being loaded last in dev.

Comment: no i dont think this is the solution on my problem. I tried to declare Schemas directly in helper, but it work on local and not work after deploy